# Where does the 'nominative object' go?

Tags: sentence-structure

So, I realise that you probably shouldn't think of Chinese sentences in terms of Latin grammar, right? That is probably doomed to failure. But on the other hand, I have noticed that often, Chinese sentences push the nominative object/the subject of the sentence after the verb that it is supposedly doing, and I'm not too sure why this structure is sometimes preferred to a standard S V O approach.
I should point out here that I'm not referring to a O V structure such as 我的车该擦了which implies the passive.

This is probably best explained using some examples. So, here goes...

1. 朋友要的词典玛丽买到了 - here, I could understand both 玛丽把朋友要的词典买到了 and 玛丽买到了朋友要的词典 but the structure above seems a bit... random
2. 前面开一辆车 - why not 一辆车在前面开?

Any thoughts or links very welcome - not sure what to search for!

Thanks, Hashamyim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all subsumed under "[topicalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization)". Chinese does it, but so do others (even Latin!). Indeed, most languages have a way of focusing on something, and Chinese allows certain word orders.

The first example is ["object NP fronting"](https://open.library.ubc.ca/cIRcle/collections/ubctheses/831/items/1.0088905) or ["object preposing"](http://www.ling.sinica.edu.tw/files/publication/j2002_4_03_5437.pdf).

> **朋友要的词典** 玛丽 **买到了**

comes from...

> 玛丽 **买到了** **朋友要的词典**

This is particularly favoured when the wording of the object is long, and especially when it is much longer than the subject.

The second example is [locative inversion](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.8071&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

> **前面** 开着 **一辆车**

(In general [the sentence](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.8071&rep=rep1&type=pdf) would require a 着 here.)

The more canonical sentence

> **一辆车** **(在)前面** 开着

... doesn't sound as good for this sentence.

Only specific types of verbs are permitted to undergo locative inversion, [specifically](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4047855.pdf) unaccusative and passivised verbs. There are very few transitive verbs that can do so, most notably 放 *fàng*.

These non-SVO orders have several different functions. This locative inversion has [two main ones](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.8071&rep=rep1&type=pdf): describing the landscape, and *presentation focus*. These two are relatively similar to English, although the specific number of verbs allowed by English in this construction is lower.

Comment: Wow. That is insanely helpful. Am looking up topicalisation now :-) Do you fancy being my Chinese tutor? Lol

Comment: +1 for increasing my knowledge. I'd also say that topicalisation in Chinese may be also used to make an object plural (when the subject is singular) with 都, as in 朋友要的词典玛丽都卖到了。