# Passive object position in 是...的 structure?

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-structure, phrase, word-order

I came across the following sentences:

1. > 电话是谁打来的?
   >
   > Diànhuà shì shuí dǎlái de?
   >
   > Who was calling?
2. > 晚饭是妈妈做的。
   >
   > Wǎnfàn shì māma zuò de.
   >
   > Mom made dinner.

Which literally is something like:

1. `The phone call was by who done?`
2. `Dinner is by mama done.`

This looks quite *passive* to me as the object appears first in the sentence.

**Question 1**:  I don't understand the word order. Is it because the structure 是...的 allows for passive sentences? I couldn't find any resources explaining this such as in [The "shi... de" construction for emphasizing details in resources.allsetlearning](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/The_%22shi..._de%22_construction_for_emphasizing_details). Could you provide some?

Instead, I would have expected the object to be positioned before or after the 的 (as explained in the section [Position of 的](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/The_%22shi..._de%22_construction_for_emphasizing_details#Position_of_.E7.9A.84) from the previous link)：

1. `是谁打来电话的?` or `是谁打来的电话?`
2. `是妈妈做晚饭的.` or `是妈妈做的晚饭.`

**Question 2**: Just to clarify, would this form be correct too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**question 1**

> I don't understand how is it allowed this order structure. Is it because the structure 是...的 allows for passive sentences?

是 ～ 的 is typically used for emphasis.

The position of the object in your two example sentences is given by the topic-comment construction, which is typical in Chinese.

If we break it down:

> 晚饭 topic
>
> (是)妈妈做(的) comment, with additional emphasis given by 是 ～ 的

It appears passive only if you go out of your way to keep the same word order in English.

**question 2**

> Just to clarify, would this form be correct too?

I would say that `是谁打来电话的?` and `是妈妈做晚饭的` don't feel right to me.

Whereas `是谁打来的电话` and `是妈妈做的晚饭` do, even though they shift the focus of the sentence on "who" and "mum" respectively: "who is it who called" and "it's mum who made dinner".

Comment: 1. I guess having the topic before the comment is allowed by the phenomena of "[topicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization)" (see also [this other post](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/34423/25265) ). Is it usual in chinese to have this order? Does it sound a little bit stranger than the usual order?
2. You say having the object before 的 sounds weird to you. Maybe writing the object after 的 is more common in chinese because it gives more clarity to the detail that is emphasized...

Comment: Chinese IS a topic-comment language. In informal speech maybe you find it less often, but topic-comment order is how the language works most of the time. As of where to place the object w.r.t 的，it depends on the role 的 has in the sentence

Comment: Ah, I really didn't understood the *topic-comment construction* before. I'll just leave a link here if someone else has the same difficulty: [Topic-comment sentences in resources.allsetlearning.com](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Topic-comment_sentences)

Answer (score 3):

> In "是谁打来的电话" , the object is '电话'
>
> [电话]是谁打来的 (places the object before the verb emphasize the object, makes it a more important part in the sentence - The phone call is the topic)

~

In "是妈妈做的晚饭" , the object is '晚饭'

> [晚饭] 是妈妈做的 (place the object before the verb emphasize the object, makes it a more important part in the sentence - The dinner is the topic)

[的] marks 是谁打来[的] as an 'adjectival phrase' that describes the object to follow. In this case, it describes the object 电话 (phone call? What phone call? The phone call that was made by who)

[的] marks 是妈妈做[的] as an 'adjectival phrase' that describes the object to follow. In this case, it describes the object 晚饭 (dinner? What dinner? The dinner that was made by mother)

*是 = (it) is/ (it) was*

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the meaning of the two sentences is similar, which is related to the habit of speaking and tone of voice.

Q: 是谁做的晚饭?
Answer: 是妈妈做的晚饭.
Q: 晚饭是谁做的? 
Answer: 晚饭是妈妈做的.

Here have three words and different orders can be used to express the level of eating chili:
不怕辣；辣不怕；怕不辣. 
Your choice is...